# jQuery check value of multiple radio buttons

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button

I have a series of radio buttons as follows:

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="-1" />

<input type="radio" name="r2" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="-1" />

<input type="radio" name="r3" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="-1" />
```

What I need to do is run a check to see if **any of the radio buttons selected** have a value `equal to or less than 2 but greater than zero`, and then run some code or `greater than 2` and if they do, run some further code.

I have achieved this previously using javascript but it has been a long and laborious process.  Is there an efficient way in jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? And also, why do you have a radiobutton with value -1 if you want code to run if the value is equal to or less then 2 but greater than zero.

Comment: If it makes it easier, I can modify the code to replace the -1 with 'X' but it's legacy code and I want to change as little as possible of what is there already.  In terms of previous code it was literally checking to see if each and every checkbox was checked using javascript - such as: `document.getElementById('r1a1').checked = false;` (where rqa1 was the id for the radio button) for each and every radio button - fine if there are only a few but on some pages I'm going to have in the region of 50 plus radio buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
    if (this.value > 0 && this.value <= 2) {
       // do something if the value is less than zero and below or equal to two
    }else if (this.value > 2) {
       // do something else if the value is greater than two
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this code have to be fired each time a user selects a radio button or can it fired after the user has selected the last radio button?

Comment: @Homer_J - that's impossible to answer, do whatever you like. If you like to run the code each time a radio is selected, you do that, if you have a "submit" or something like that when the user has finished selecting, you can check everything before submitting etc. It's really up to you!

Comment: Apologies, just trying to get my head around jQuery - if I fire this code on a form `submit` does it check every radio button on the page?

Comment: With that selector it will check every `checked` radiobutton on the page. Note that when you submit a form the default action is to reload the page, and all javascript will be lost at that time.

Comment: Thanks - I'm having a problem getting this to run when a user clicks a radio button.  I'm assuming I should wrap this in a function and call it via the `onclick` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
  if((this.val() > 0) && (this.val() <=2)) {
    //Todos
   }
  else if(this.val() > 2) {
   //Todos
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $lessOrEqual2AndGreatZero = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').filter(function(elem){
    return ($(elem).val() > 0 && $(elem).val() <= 2);
});


if ($lessOrEqual2AndGreatZero.length){
   // code
} else {
    var $greaterThanTwo = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').filter(function(elem){
        return ($(elem).val() > 2);
    });
    if ($greaterThanTwo.length){
        // more code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question:

```
var check = $(':radio:checked').is(function () {
    return this.value <= 2 && this.value > 0
});

if(check)
   //at least one radio button which is checked as value > 0 but less or equal to 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var radios = $('input[type="radio"]');

function areAnyInRange() {
    return radios.filter(':checked').filter(function() {
       return (+this.value > 0 && +this.value <= 2);
    }).length > 0;
}

function inRange() {
    if(areAnyInRange()) {
       console.log('radios in range!');    
    } else {
        console.log('no radios in range :(');   
    }
}

inRange();
radios.change(inRange);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZfeT/1/

How the code works:

- `areAnyInRange` loops through checked radios and returns true if any
  values are in range
- this fun is called once on code execution and then each time radios change